# Align image div on the right with 3 vertical text divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to right-align an image div which contains my display picture with three separate divs on the left. Something like this: [div-idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBQq0.png)

```css
.title-container {
 text-align: right;
 display: inline-block;
}

.para-container {
 text-align: left;
 display: inline-block;
}

.icon-container {
    margin: auto;
}

.logo {

 display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<header>
<div class="logo-container" style="float:left;">
<h1>Title Container</h1>
</div>
</header>
<h4>
<div class="para-container" style="float:left; white-space:nowrap;">
<p>
<h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis nisl magna. Nunc <br> pharetra varius dui eu fermentum. Quisque ut neque velit. Pellentesque massa sapien, <br> consectetur non dui eu, consequat commodo ante. Phasellus ac lectus nec justo fermentum <br>congue non sed ex. Aenean in tortor ac eros maximus rhoncus a in nulla. Fusce ultricies ipsum <br>vel lacus pulvinar, auctor ultrices leo porta. Donec eu metus sit amet erat hendrerit vehicula <br>in eget lacus. 
</h3></p></div>
 
<div class="logo" style="float:right;">
<img itemprop="image" src="https://dinesh-ghimire.com.np/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/html5.png" height="200" width="200" alt="image"/></a></div>
  
<div style="clear: left;"/>
</h4>

<div class="link-container">
<a href="">Contact Me </a>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is good to be consistent with semantic and non-semantic tags. If you use `<header>`, it is expected that you also use `<article>` and `<footer>`, or other html5 semantic tags. If you don't want that, just use `<div>`'s with talking class names, i. e. "header", "article" etc.

Then, don't put other than text inside `<h3>`, `<h4>` tags. These are only for marking headings.

Also, don't use "style" and "class" attributes on html tags simultaneously. This makes the code difficult to read and maintain. If possible, put all style information into a separate css file, or at least one separate `<style>` section in the html file.

Another hint: don't use `<br>` to format long text. The browsers will do that. Only use `<br>` when you deliberately want to break the line at some point, even if it renders near the beginning of the current line.

Now getting to the point, **to arrange boxes** in some neat order, in my humble opinion the most flexible way is using CSS flexbox. I created a code that might whet your appetite for flexboxes:

CSS:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

#text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#icon-container {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

article {
  padding: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="text-container">
    <header>
      <h1>Title Container</h1>
    </header>

    <article>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis nisl magna. Nunc pharetra varius dui eu fermentum. Quisque ut neque velit. Pellentesque massa sapien, consectetur non dui eu, consequat commodo ante. Phasellus ac lectus nec justo fermentum congue non sed ex. Aenean in tortor ac eros maximus rhoncus a in nulla. Fusce ultricies ipsum vel lacus pulvinar, auctor ultrices leo porta. Donec eu metus sit amet erat hendrerit vehicula in eget lacus. 
    </article>

    <footer>
      <a href="">Contact Me</a>
    </footer>
  </div>

  <div id="icon-container">
      <img 
        itemprop="image" 
        src="https://dinesh-ghimire.com.np/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/html5.png" 
        height="200"
        width="200" 
        alt="image"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yx0vjda9/)

And a superb [guide to flexbox at css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) where all the features are nicely illustrated.

Answer (score 0):

you're probably going to want to use css grid for this one. add this css to the parent container

```
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
```

and then (referencing the image you posted for classnames) add these to the children containers

```
.title {
grid-row: 1;
grid-column: 1;
}

.paragraph {
grid-row: 2;
grid-column: 1;
}

.linkDiv {
grid-row: 3;
grid-column: 1;
}

.imageDiv {
grid-row-start: 1;
grid-row-end: 4;
grid-column: 2;
}
```

this should do the trick for displaying like the image you provided.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.title-container {
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

.para-container {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.icon-container {
    margin: auto;
}

.logo {

    display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<h4>
        <div style="overflow: hidden;">
            <div class="para-container" style="float:left; white-space:nowrap;">
                <div class="logo-container" style="width: 100%;">
                    <h1>Title Container</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <h3>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis nisl magna. Nunc <br> pharetra varius dui eu fermentum. Quisque ut neque velit. Pellentesque massa sapien, <br> consectetur non dui eu, consequat commodo ante. Phasellus ac lectus nec justo fermentum <br>congue non sed ex. Aenean in tortor ac eros maximus rhoncus a in nulla. Fusce ultricies ipsum <br>vel lacus pulvinar, auctor ultrices leo porta. Donec eu metus sit amet erat hendrerit vehicula <br>in eget lacus. 
                    </h3>
                </p>

                <div class="link-container">
                    <a href="">Contact Me </a>
                </div>
            </div>
                
            <div class="logo" style="float:right;">
                <a><img itemprop="image" src="https://dinesh-ghimire.com.np/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/html5.png" height="200" width="200" alt="image"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the image element at the top and float it to the right to disturb the normal layout float. I just added a suggestion which help you to continue. try to use div element and style them according in case for bold and bigger size ( like title ) 
Hope this could help.

```css
img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<img itemprop="image" src="https://dinesh-ghimire.com.np/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/html5.png" height="200" width="200" alt="image" />
<div>Text Div1 Title</div>
<div> Text Div2 Paragrpah</div>
<div>
  Link Div </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, i see what youre trying to do - have you tried flex instead of using block layout? if not i recommend it, its wel.. flexy: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c1b02sy7/

HTML

```
<header class="wrapper">

   <content class="box first">
     <div class="title">
     <h2 class="title-string">A Title here</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="paragraph">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis nisl magna. Nunc <br> pharetra varius dui eu fermentum. Quisque ut neque velit. Pellentesque massa sapien, <br> consectetur non dui eu, consequat commodo ante. Phasellus ac lectus nec justo fermentum <br>congue non sed ex. Aenean in tortor ac eros maximus rhoncus a in nulla. Fusce ultricies ipsum <br>vel lacus pulvinar, auctor ultrices leo porta. Donec eu metus sit amet erat hendrerit vehicula <br>in eget lacus.</p>
    </div>
     <div class="link">
     <a href="#" alt>Link name goes here</a>
    </div>
  </content>

   <content class="box second">
    <span class="image random-image-link">
    </span>
  </content>  

</header>
```

CSS

```
/* Main wrapper */
header.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  min-height:100%;
  min-width:100%;  
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;

  align-items:flex-start;
}

/* default inner wrapper | two boxes */
content.box {
  display:flex;
  height:50%;
  width:50%;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* Image container and link */
.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
/* Keep things modular */
.image.random-image-link {
  background-image: url(https://dinesh-ghimire.com.np/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/html5.png);
}

/* Typography */
p, h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,div, span {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
h2.title-string {
  font-size:1.75em;
  color:red;
  }
```